# Running SPARK with SQL file from python gives error

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to call a .SQL file with hive queries from Python py file using SPARK. It gives Error -- AttributeError: 'Builder' object has no attribute 'SparkContext'

Looked at multiple posts with similar error and tried but none of them worked for me. Here is my code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext  
sc = SparkSession.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
with open("/apps/home/p1.sql") as fr:
   query = fr.read()
   results = sc.sql(query)
```

The p1.sql has sql queries. How to pass parameters to the sql file? what will be different if sql returns rows and does not return rows. New to SPARK. Appreciate if the answer gives the code lines. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

with open("/apps/home/p1.sql") as fr:
   query = fr.read()
   results = spark.sql(query)
```

You can refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#starting-point-sparksession

Comment: I get error: pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous input ';' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 53)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect name from warehouse.users limit 5;\n-----------------------------------------------------^^^\n"                            The query works fine running from CLI

Comment: It seems file reading issue, try put sql inside `spark.sql(query)` directly.

Comment: I try all means and still get the same error.